# I have already installed pynotify, still getting error no module named pynotify

Tags: python, pynotify

I have already installed pynotify using :

```
pip install py-notify
```

When I re-run this it shows :

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade).

I also tried :

```
pip install --upgrade py-notify
```

but it shows :

> Requirement already up-to-date.

Below is my simple code to show desktop notification using pynotify.

```
import pynotify    
pynotify.init("Basic")

n = pynotify.Notification("Title", "Some sample content")
n.show()
```

What should I do now to run below code correctly?

Comment: You don't by any chance have two instances of Python installed? For example Python is included in the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: No. I have only Python 2.7.9 installed in my system. I am using ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: @Kake_Fisk what happens if two instances of python is installed ,bcz i am also facing the same issue and i have Anaconda distribution also .(i am using macOs)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to send GTK balloons - you've not installed correct library.

If you want to use "Observer programming pattern" (callback management) - you are using incorrect syntax.

There are two similar packages:

- pynotify - wrapper for libnotify that shows desktop balloons to notify user about some events. Requires PyGTK (`http://www.pygtk.org/`) to work. Can't be installed from `pip`. Usually installed with some OS package (something like `python-pynotify`). Usage: `import pygtk;pygtk.require('2.0');import pynotify`.
- notify2 (`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2`) - alternative wrapper for libnotify. Can be installed from `pip`. Usage: `import notify2`

There are also two unrelated packages with similar names:

- pyinotify (`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinotify`) - wrapper for lib**i**notify that allows to monitor filesystem changes. Usage: `import pyinotify`.
- py-notify (`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-notify`) - python-only library that implements hooks (callback) storage, calling and filtering with no connections to outside world (third-party libraries or standards). Usage: `import notify`.

Answer (score 1):

faced same problem on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install python-notify
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There's a names conflict with `pynotify`.

I had installed pynotify from PIP using:

```
sudo pip install pynotify
```

Since that was the wrong choice, I removed it with:

---

```
sudo pip uninstall pynotify
```

And then installed the expected pynotify using:

```
sudo apt install python-notify
```