# pynotify gets an error in python2.7 in windows10

Tags: python, python-2.7

When i used to code pynotify for python2.7 in Windows 10 then it shows an error that module object has no attribute 'init'. And i have already done to install the init module but same error occur. so what are the possible  solutions for this problem? 
here the code is.

```
import pynotify
pynotify.init("Basic")
n = pynotify.Notification("Title","Some sample content")
n.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `pynotify` package you are looking for was initially designed for linux and was never supposed work on windows

**The `pynotify` package installable through `pip` is just a name collision, and is not what not what you are looking for**. (as this stackoverflow thread shows : [I have already installed pynotify, still getting error no module named pynotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085869/i-have-already-installed-pynotify-still-getting-error-no-module-named-pynotify))

The package you want has GTK dependencies and can be installed in linux-based systems through the package management system using commands like : `sudo apt-get install pynotify`.

Other similar packages like `notify2` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2) require linux components like `dbus`, and thus are not windows compatible.

If you're looking for a way to make **windows 10 notifications**, you can probably have look at this repository https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications.